# How to get the first 2 characters from a string in a list and create a new column with it in python?

Tags: python

apologies first as I am new to python and not sure if I am allowed to ask this here.   I am trying to extract the first 2 letter from a column containing postcodes

I have created a list and then tried to use the slicing methods described in all the documents and whatever I could find in the post here.  the nearest I got to was reading the article 'Get the first character of a the first string in a list?' however I am only able to read the whole postcode from the list instead of partial.

for example `mylist[3][:2]` brings me back `['TS3 1HU']` when I was expecting AB, the 4th postcode in my list with the characters upto 2.  I created a list by reading a file with the csv module.

can anyone help or direct me to some help?  I understand the concept and can do it for a single string its when it is a list of strings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like `mylist[3]` is the list `['TS3 1HU']` rather than the string `'TS3 1HU'`; try `mylist[3][0][:2]`.

Comment: It would help to have a working example of your code, the structure it uses, and example data...

Comment: I suspect, if your original data structure came from `csv`, that it's a list of lists of strings.

Comment: Yea, example data (first few rows) would help.